# How to communicate between FieldEditors in RCP

Tags: model-view-controller, eclipse-rcp, hmvc, fieldeditor

I have a PreferencePage that extends from FieldEditorPreferencePage and to it I'm adding two TableFieldEditors (which extends from FieldEditor) as follows

```
@Override
protected void createFieldEditors() {
    TableFieldEditor activeProfileTable = new ActiveProfileTableFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.GRADING_PROFILE, gradeProfileService, getFieldEditorParent());
    TableFieldEditor draftProfileTable = new DraftProfileTableFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.GRADING_PROFILE, gradeProfileService, getFieldEditorParent());
    addField(activeProfileTable);
    addField(draftProfileTable);
}
```

I need the two TableFieldEditors to communicate with each other, how should I do it?

I don't want to use the EventBus for this purpose, is there a better way, something along the lines of HMVC?

Comment: There isn't anything like HMVC.

Comment: @greg-449 By Hierarchical Model View Controller (HMVC) I wanted a design where I compose these editors such that there is a parent in their hierarchy which can orchestrate their communication.